# Extend Style in wpf

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, tooltip

I tried the following way to extend style and add tooltip message if validationresult is true. But it shows error "Property style is set more than once". How can I extend style for this case. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

```
<TextBox Width="500" Style="{StaticResource HasInvalidValue}">
                <TextBox.Text>
                    <Binding Path="Text" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged">
                        <Binding.ValidationRules>
                            <Validator:PathFormatValidationRule/>
                        </Binding.ValidationRules>
                    </Binding>
                </TextBox.Text>
                <TextBox.Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}" BasedOn="{StaticResource HasInvalidValue}">
                    <Style>
                        <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="Enter Text."/>
                    </Style>
                </TextBox.Style>
            </TextBox>
```

And the style is defined as:

```
<Style x:Key="HasInvalidValue" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="Validation.HasError" Value="true">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="White"/>
            <Setter Property="ToolTip"
          Value="{Binding RelativeSource={x:Static RelativeSource.Self},
                          Path=(Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent}"/>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Comment: You're setting `Style` twice, once by binding to `StaticResource` and then manually a little further down. Moreover, you overwrite the `Tooltip.Value` in the second style assignment to a hard coded value, which doesn't make much sense...

Comment: Remove specifying Style on the element itself(Style="{StaticResource HasInvalidValue}") When you have a style with BasedOn the derived from style is applied automatically.

Comment: I removed binding and applied it. I changed basedon to style instead of textbox.style. It worked. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First is set in

```
<TextBox Style="{StaticResource HasInvalidValue}" ...
...
</TextBox>
```

and then

```
<TextBox.Style ...
</TextBox.Style>
```

From textbox element remove the style attribute.